# How to determine which welcome file has to be shown with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I'm figuring out how to provide the correct welcome page. I have to show the login page if none user is logged, otherwise i have to show other page that will call RESTful services developed in [Jesey](https://jersey.java.net/) to change the interface. Any idea to switch between the pages configured at `welcome-files` that are placed in `web.xml`

Comment: The list of welcome files does not change. You redirect or forward based on the presence of a logged in user.

Comment: I just ask because a i see many applications with more than one welcome files